# Is composable architecture the same as PaaS

Tags: architecture, paas

according to the definition found in this website composable architecture is:

https://www.hpe.com/us/en/what-is/composable-infrastructure.html

```
In composable infrastructure, compute, storage, and networking resources are abstracted 
from their physical locations,and can be managed by software, through a web-based interface. 
Composable infrastructure makes data center resources as readily available as cloud services, and is the foundation for private and hybrid cloud 
solutions.
```

what is the difference between composable architecture and Platform as a Service such as AWS services?

can I say if Im running in AWS that I have a composable architecture?

Comment: Infrastructure and architecture are two different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, composable infrastructure is an infrastructure; not a platform and therefore its comparison with PaaS is not correct. The comparison should be with IaaS, not PaaS.

The most basic difference between a composable infrastructure and IaaS is that in case of composable infrastructure, it's you who manage everything (in your own datacentre) while in case of IaaS, a part of the infrastructure management goes to the hands of IaaS provider. You can check https://www.bmc.com/blogs/saas-vs-paas-vs-iaas-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-choose/ to understand what you manage and what the cloud providers manage.

Composable infrastructure is a way to get the flexibility of IaaS using the virtualization management tools and technologies like Chef, Puppet and Docker in your existing datacentre. You can check https://techbeacon.com/enterprise-it/5-things-you-need-know-about-composable-infrastructure for more information.

Comment: I see, thank you so much, now I get the different. thank you so much.